# Using clearInterval in nested call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JS that creates a graph. The graph is rendered first and keeps updating it every 3 seconds as below.

I would like to stop the execution of the script using clearInterval or some other way whenever a button is clicked. How can I achieve that?

I understand how clearInterval works, but, I am not able to figure out how to control the nested setInterval depending on an event.

Disclaimer: I am kinda new to JS etc.

```js
mystats = function () {
  this.render = function() {
    var graph = vendorgraph();
    graph.render();

    setInterval( function() {
      jsonupdate.addData(seriesData,url);
      graph.update();
    }, 3000 );
  }
}

var mytrends = new mystats(); 
mytrends.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval returns a value, you can use that value to stop it later, maybe by storing it in some interval array.

```
var intervalArray = [];

mystats = function () {
  this.render = function() {
    var graph = vendorgraph();
    graph.render();

    var interval = setInterval( function() {
      jsonupdate.addData(seriesData,url);
      graph.update();
    }, 3000 );
    intervalArray.push(interval);
  }
}    

// later on
var intervalVariable = intervalArray[0];
clearInterval(intervalVariable)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to get it running without luck. The thing is mystats is a separate JS file, so am not able to control that global from my HTML.

Comment: This was to be an example, but do you understand the concept? You have to store the return value for access later.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt quite do what you suggested, but, got a hint form what you did. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint from other post by Zach and solved it this way

```js
mystats = function () {
  var interval;
  this.render = function() {
    var graph = vendorgraph();
    graph.render();

    interval = setInterval( function() {
      jsonupdate.addData(seriesData,url);
      graph.update();
    }, 3000 );
  }
  this.stoprender = function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

var mytrends = new mystats(); 
mytrends.render(); 
on my event {
   mytrends.stoprender();
}
```